# Writing to local file during map phase in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop writes the intermediate results to the local disk and the results of the reducer to the HDFS. what does HDFS mean. What does it physically translate to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDFS is the Hadoop Distributed File System. Physically, it is a program running on each node of the cluster that provides a file system interface very similar to that of a local file system. However, data written to HDFS is not just stored on the local disk but rather is distributed on disks across the cluster. Data stored in HDFS is typically also replicated, so the same block of data may appear on multiple nodes in the cluster. This provides reliable access so that one node's crashing or being busy will not prevent someone from being able to read any particular block of data from HDFS.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop_Distributed_File_System#Hadoop_Distributed_File_System for more information.

Answer (score 2):

As Chase indicated, HDFS is Hadoop Distributed File System.

If I may, I recommend this tutorial and video of how HDFS and the Map/Reduce framework works and will serve you as a guide into the world of Hadoop: http://www.cloudera.com/resource/introduction-to-apache-mapreduce-and-hdfs/